# Offset of User Code for Bootloader XMC4500 ARM Cortex M4

Tags: arm, offset, bootloader, m4

I've made a bootloader and a windows application which communicate. The windows application sends the hex file (user app with an offset starting at 0x0C008000) to the bootloader which stores it at the address in flash. The data of the hex file is stored at the right address. I've checked it by reading the flash.

The bootloader waits for 3 seconds to receive a sign. If there is no sign received then it willjump to the user app.

The Jump is not working and I dont know why. Bootloader starts at 0x0C000000.
In the linker script of the user app i mapped the memory regions like this (starting at 0x0C008000)

```
MEMORY
{
FLASH_1_cached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x08008000, LENGTH = 0xf8000
FLASH_1_uncached(RX) : ORIGIN = 0x0C008000, LENGTH = 0xf8000
PSRAM_1(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x10000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
DSRAM_1_system(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x10000
DSRAM_2_comm(!RX) : ORIGIN = 0x30000000, LENGTH = 0x8000
}
```

The code of the jump is following

```
void RunFlash(void)
{
   PPB->VTOR = 0x0c008000; // Offset of the Vector

   asm("ldr r0, =0x0c008000");
   asm("ldr r1, =0xE000ED08");
   asm("str r0,[r1]");
   asm("ldr sp, [r0], #4");
   asm("ldr r15, [R0]");
}
```

I always get an "No source available for "0x80082b0" error.

Can somebody please help me? Do i need to make additional changes to the linker script? Do i need to change something in the startup code?

I'm using an Infenion XMC4500 and DAVE4 IDE.

Comment: Hmm sounds like this is a big mistake. The code isnt mine, I took it from the Infenion Bootloader Example. Can you please tell me how it is done?

Comment: Bah, my mistake, I somehow read the post-increment as an offset. Looking at it again, that address would appear to be the cacheable alias of some part of the application - what's the actual reset vector being loaded (i.e. the value of the word at 0xc008004)?